# Purely excel formula with network days

Tags: excel, excel-formula, multiple-conditions

I have this spreadsheet to track how long a team is taking to complete customer requests.  I've coded the net days considering holidays and work week for different team members but when 'L2' is blank (case completed date) my formula is returning odd values such as '30520'

I want to tell excel that is L2 is blank, then ignore my formula and leave the cell blank, else display the calculated value. I am also okay with displaying OPEN if L2 is found empty.  This is what my formula looks like:

```
=IF(OR(B2="Jack", B2="Jill"),NETWORKDAYS.INTL(K2,L2,1,O$2:O$11),
    NETWORKDAYS.INTL(K2,L2,7,Q$2:Q$26))
```

Where:

```
B2 = case owner
K2= case received date
L2 = case completed date
O = set of US holidays
Q = set of intl’ holidays
```

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Could you give us some sample data? And then maybe good output when L2 is filled in and the error you get when L2 is blank? As it is, this will be difficult for someone to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to tell excel that is L2 is blank, then ignore my formula and leave the cell blank

Well, that's easy enough to do with just any formula: Wrap another IF statement around the formula

```
=if(L2="","",<theFormula>)
```

Comment: Thanks Teylyn.  I just saw your response now; my problem was also that the target cell was formatted date.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to this in a different forum.  I used the following:
=IF(L2="","OPEN",IF(OR(B2="Jack", B2="Jill"),NETWORKDAYS.INTL(K2,L2,1,O$2:O$11),NETWORKDAYS.INTL(K2,L2,7,Q$2:Q$26)))

Also, I formatted my target cell as "general" and it worked wonders!